# Substituting class name by variable in PHP

Tags: php

Since which version of PHP is it possible to use the following:

```
$class::method()->something($val);
```

I need to use this but in 5.2.11 I get a T_PAMAAYIM_whatever error, and I just wanted to determine whether it's version related or bad coding.

If it's version related, what's a valid alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a PHP 5.3 feature. You should be able to `call_user_func(array($class, $method), $val);` in "any" version.

Answer (score 0):

Added in PHP 5.3. From the release notes:

> New features
>
> - **Dynamic access to static methods is now possible.**

http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a PHP5.3 feature. For now use `call_user_func(array('Class', 'method'), $arg)`, and in the future [PHP5.4 will even make it possible](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/indirect-method-call-by-array-var) to do:

```
$callback = array('Class', 'method');
$callback($arg);
```